# How to split a decimal by its dot into integers using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, split

I have the following code;

```
var looptijd_1 = de_snelheid * de_afstand;
var split_looptijden_1 = new Array();
split_looptijden_1 = looptijd_1.split('.');
```

As you can see, is the idea very simple. I want to split an number by its dot. So if the number is `69.07`, i want an variable with `69` and an variable with `07`.

I know I have to make a string of the variable and split them, but I need the `07` as `07` and not `7` (because I've got the do some math with it).

I know that I can take the first value, and store that, then the variable - the stored variable, so I've got `0.07`, but I hope there's an better way tho achieve this, because this needs to be done 12 times on the page.

Is there a better way to achieve my goal (`variable1 = 69; variable2=07`) and both integers?

EDIT;
The whole point, is that this is math about walking time... And there are none constant variables, so i lop them, and then i would like to do the trick (numbers after the dot * 60)

Comment: parseInt(07) = 7   so it's a bit hard to hold that variable as int ;)

Comment: @Ahmet: And bonus points if you can tell -- without trying it -- what `parseInt('010')` will return!

Comment: I think you need to post the entire section of relevant code. It sounds like you're making something more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: Presumably the OP just wants to preserve the difference between `69.07` and `69.70` etc. The correct approach is to keep the numbers as numbers rather than converting to string, splitting, parsing etc.

Comment: @LukeH i didn't guess `parseInt('010')=8` without trying.

Comment: Javascript is limited in its ability to do math operations on decimal numbers.  Crockford talks about this in "The Good Parts"... He suggests for any monetary calculations to multiply the entire number by 100, do your math on the whole number, and then devide the result by 100 before returning your value.  If you're looking to do a more complex mathematical operation, you're probably out of luck.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're wanting to perform calculations with the results then there's no need to convert your number to a string, split it, and then convert the resulting strings back to numbers. Use some basic maths instead:

```
var split_looptijden_1 =
    [
        (looptijd_1 > 0) ? Math.floor(looptijd_1) : Math.ceil(looptijd_1),
        looptijd_1 % 1
    ];
```

Comment: If my input is 1.1 I want to get 1 and 0.1. Current result is 1 and 0.100.. how can I accomplish it? As with commas, the [right value gets printed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator), so I need to `toFixed(1)` around the modulo? I do not understand what modulo does here? division by 1?

Comment: Seems to work, but I do not grasp the function of `comma` in`else`: `input=1.1;out=[(input > 0) ?math.floor(input) : math.ceil(input),(input % 1).toFixed(1)]`

Answer (score 6):

```
This is my assumption:

Convert your decimal number into string and then split it using .split() method then store the result into an array.

var num=10.07;
var str=num.toString();
var numarray=str.split('.');
var a=new Array();
a=numarray;
console.log(a[0]);
console.log(a[1]);
```

try with the below example, you will get your desired result.If console.log() not worked

```
its working fine for me.

Demo:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo">Integer Part</p>
<p id="demo1">Decimal Part</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction()
{

var num=10.07;
var str=num.toString();
var numarray=str.split('.');
var a=new Array();
a=numarray;


var x = document.getElementById("demo");
var y = document.getElementById("demo1");
x.innerHTML=a[0];
y.innerHTML=a[1];
}demo1
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the number a string (it's a number at the moment, which can't be `split`), then split it:

```
var split_looptijden_1 = looptijd_1.toString().split('.');
console.log(split_looptijden_1[0]); // 69
console.log(split_looptijden_1[1]); // 07
```

NB that the `new Array()` is not necessary. `split` returns a new array anyway; the one you created is overwritten. Since Javascript uses static typing, you don't need to declare a variable's type. Note also that, if you want integers, you'll have to forget leading zeros. If you want a particular way of formatting characters, that's called a string.

Comment: but do you know an way to make the number 07, 07... or isn't there a way?

Comment: `07 === 7` There is no difference. If you want to do calculations, they are precisely the same. If you want to display `07`, use a string. End of.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what u need

```
var looptijd_1 = de_snelheid * de_afstand;
var split_looptijden_1 = new Array();
split_looptijden_1 = (looptijd_1+"").split('.');
```

Answer (score 0):

You must convert the number to a string first:

```
split_looptijden_1 = looptijd_1.toString().split('.');
```

Comment: i know, but i was looking for an way around, so i can achief my goal

Comment: You didn't quite explain your goal then... Your original code did not work, so I doubt you knew this.  So, why do you need them to be integer type?  They are now strings in an array, which you can access as you please, and if they need to be integers at some point you can use parseInt.

Comment: The whole point, is that this is math about walking time... And there are none constant variables, so i lop them, and then i would like to do the trick (numbers after the dot * 60)

Comment: Then simply `parseInt(split_looptijden_1[1]) * 60`.  What is the problem??

Comment: it makes diffrnce if the number is 07 or 7 :P

Comment: `07` is not a number, as many people have told you on this page.  It is `7` no matter what you do with it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make an array. Split does this automatically.

```
var looptijd_1 = de_snelheid * de_afstand + "";
var split_looptijden_1 = looptijd_1.split('.');
```

Comment: alright, handy to know, but not the answer i was looking for ;P

Comment: @TWCrap: Then what are you looking for? Obviously you cannot store `07` as *integer* because they don't have leading zeros. `07` and `7` represent the same value anyways.

Answer (score 0):

An integer can't be stored with leading zeros.

Try:

```
var looptijd_1 = de_snelheid * de_afstand;
var split_looptijden_1 = looptijd_1.toString().split('.');
```

This will convert the integer values to strings, thereby storing the `07` rather than `7`.

Comment: But as far as i know, i cant do math with strings, so i have to make an integer of it, and would it be 7... so does you know an way that i can make my intereger 07???

Comment: You can't make an integer `07`; it won't store that way. What math operations are you doing to where you need the zero? 7 and 07 are the same number...

Comment: @TWCrap: You do realize that `7 * 60` and `07 * 60` are both `420`, right?

Answer (score 0):

Pros:

- This solution does not use the "first value" (67) when calculating the "second" (0.07). (Words the original poster used, in " ")
- It also avoids storing 0.06999999999999318 instead of 0.07 by using the factor 1000. Increase the factor to e.g. 10000 to handle e.g. 0.007. (*10 for each additional digit)
- Works as expected for negative values. Does no rounding or conversions.

Note: This solution ignores the request for "07", which was just part of a suboptimal solution mixed into the answer.

```
variable1 = looptijd_1|0;                // = 69 as number. No rounding.
variable2 = (looptijd_1*1000%1000)/1000; // = 0.07 as number. Simple form: x % 1
```

Apart from the solution:

You said that you need to do this 12 times in one page. But you did not tell whether your concern is the time needed to calculate or cluttered code. Or both.

Time can be ignored for 12 times these simple calculations.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that the exercise include deciding on what precision you want the decimal value to be output as. This would make the value more useful and you can ignore the issue of preceding zeros.

Here is some Timer example that utilizes this idea. Make note of `splitToPrecision(n,d)`:

```
class Timer {
    constructor() {this.start();}
    start() { this.startT = (new Date()).getTime() / 1000 }
    stop() { this.stopT = (new Date()).getTime()  / 1000 }
    elapsed(prec) {
        prec=typeof prec === 'undefined' || isNaN(prec) || prec < 0?3:prec;
        var a=splitToPrecision((this.stopT - this.startT), 3)
        return nToFixed(a[0] + (a[1] / 1000), prec)
    }
}

function nToFixed(n,d) {
    if(isNaN(d)){d=0}
    var sN=String(n),iInd=sN.indexOf('.')
    if (iInd > -1 && sN.length-(iInd+1) > d){ 
        return Number(sN+"1").toFixed(d) 
    }
    return Number(n).toFixed(d)
}

function splitToPrecision(i, n){
    var iNew = nToFixed(i, n)
    var a = String(iNew).split('.')
    a[0] = parseInt(a[0])
    if (a.length === 0) { a.push(0); } else{ a[1] = parseInt(a[1]) }
    return a
}
```

Test this code out with:

```
timer = new Timer()
setTimeout(()=>{
    console.log("timeout called")
    timer.stop()
    console.log(`elapsed: ${timer.elapsed(2)}`)
}, 1234)
```

Output: `elapsed: 1.31`

This methodology is similar to how the now deprecated function in *Node.js* worked [process.hrtime([time])](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_hrtime_time) which made a Timer tool in Node much simpler.